# C# Web Service Return PDF stored as BLOB to PDF

Tags: c#, web-services, pdf

I'm pretty new at C# (and Visual Studio). So far I have successfully deployed a WEB Service which reads data from a local MSSQL server but I would like to extend it, with VS2010.

I have a local mySQL database which, among other data, has a BLOB column which stores a PDF file. I would like to read this BLOB column and return the result, from the web service, as a PDF file. The service will be called from PHP, where in similar situations I was able to present the PDF with no much effort.

So far, googling it, I was able to read the data and store it as a local file. I would like to not store the data in a file and store it in a variable (which type?) so I would be able to send this variable as the reply of the web service.

Thank you!

(I have a strong PHP background, but I find some difficulties 'translating' this background to VS)

Comment: How are you implementing the web service? ASP.net? MVC?

Comment: WCF Service Application. I just copy it to a local IIS and call it from PHP applications.

Answer (score 0):

first of all - why not VS2015? The community Edition is free and supports extensions. No reason to live in the past :)

To your question, I think that you're only missing header information.

if you add this as a mime type to your output, you should be home free:

i.e:

```
var pdfBytes = DocumentRepository.GetPdfAsByteArray(myPdf);
context.Response.StatusCode = (int) HttpStatusCode.OK;
context.Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
context.Response.OutputStream.Write(pdfBytes, 0, pdfBytes.Length);
```

Comment: This sound nice, thank you. The problem is that I don't have 'DocumentRepository' library and I don't understand what type is 'context. Perhaps byte[]? I use VS2010 at work because I use an old PC which can't run latest versions.

Comment: pdfBytes would simply be a byte [], so you can extract this directly from your database and use the rest of the code, or similar to send back the response.

Comment: DocumentRepository is just an example, it is the code or method that is responsible for getting your PDF and converting it into a byte[].

The context.Response is simply your HTTP context. When you are providing a response to a http request, you typically fill  out a HTTP response code (i.e. 200 OK), a content type, and of course the body of the html. The main part of the reply to you is that you need to set these 3 in order for the client on the other end to recognize that it has made a successful http request (by the status code) and what kind of data is coming (defined by content type)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=localhost;Integrated Security=SSPI;Initial Catalog=pubs;");
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT fileID, filePDF FROM myFiles", conn);   //filePDF is BLOB column

FileStream fs;                          // Writes the BLOB to a file
BinaryWriter bw;                        // Streams the BLOB to the FileStream object.

int bufferSize = 1000;                  // Max dimension of your PDF file in bytes.
byte[] outbyte = new byte[bufferSize];  // The BLOB byte[] buffer to be filled by GetBytes.
long retval;                            // The bytes returned from GetBytes.
long startIndex = 0;                    // The starting position in the BLOB output.

string fileID = "";                     // The publisher id to use in the file name.

// Open the connection and read data into the DataReader.
conn.Open();
SqlDataReader myReader = cmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.SequentialAccess);

while (myReader.Read())
{
  fileID = myReader.GetString(0);  

  fs = new FileStream("file_pdf" + fileID + ".pdf", FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write);
  bw = new BinaryWriter(fs);

  startIndex = 0;

  retval = myReader.GetBytes(1, startIndex, outbyte, 0, bufferSize);

  while (retval == bufferSize)
  {
    bw.Write(outbyte);
    bw.Flush();

    startIndex += bufferSize;
    retval = myReader.GetBytes(1, startIndex, outbyte, 0, bufferSize);
  }

  bw.Write(outbyte, 0, (int)retval - 1);
  bw.Flush();

  bw.Close();
  fs.Close();
}

myReader.Close();
conn.Disponse();
conn.Close();
```

Comment: This is indeed something which is close to what I want. I had already found this example and managed so far to read blob, write the pdf file, and then open, read and return the pdf file from local disk as a result. The steps I want to avoid is to write the pdf to a local file, and then to open it as a file.

Comment: @nasos Ok, I understand! For read the PDF file you can use iTextSharp and 'extract' the to new file

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve my problem, combining some information from here and other answers. Generally, I wanted to avoid writing the PDF from BLOB as a physical file, and then having to open and read it as a file. Thank you for your help!

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.ServiceModel.Web;
using System.Text;
using System.Configuration;
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;
using System.IO;

public MySqlConnection myInit()
{
    return new MySqlConnection(
        "host=" + ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["mysqlHost"] +
        ";user=" + ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["mysqlUser"] +
        ";password=" + ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["mysqlPass"] +
        ";database=" + ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["mysqlDb"]);
}

public Dictionary<string,byte[]> getPDF(int pdfid)
{
    string query = "SELECT md5_string, data FROM pdf,pdf_view WHERE pdf.id=" + pdfid + " and pdf_view.id=pdf.id";
    MySqlConnection con = myInit();
    MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, con);

    MemoryStream ms;
    BinaryWriter bw;                        // Streams the BLOB to the MemoryStream object.
    Dictionary<string, byte[]> result = new Dictionary<string, byte[]>();

    int bufferSize = 1000;                   // Size of the BLOB buffer.
    byte[] outbyte = new byte[bufferSize];  // The BLOB byte[] buffer to be filled by GetBytes.
    long retval;                            // The bytes returned from GetBytes.
    long startIndex = 0;

    con.Open();

    MySqlDataReader myReader = cmd.ExecuteReader(System.Data.CommandBehavior.SequentialAccess);

    while (myReader.Read())
    {
        ms = new MemoryStream();
        bw = new BinaryWriter(ms);

        string md5 = myReader.GetString(0);

        // Reset the starting byte for the new BLOB.
        startIndex = 0;

        // Read the bytes into outbyte[] and retain the number of bytes returned.
        retval = myReader.GetBytes(1, startIndex, outbyte, 0, bufferSize);

        // Continue reading and writing while there are bytes beyond the size of the buffer.
        while (retval == bufferSize)
        {
            bw.Write(outbyte);
            bw.Flush();

            // Reposition the start index to the end of the last buffer and fill the buffer.
            startIndex += bufferSize;
            retval = myReader.GetBytes(1, startIndex, outbyte, 0, bufferSize);
        }

        // Write the remaining buffer.
        bw.Write(outbyte, 0, (int)retval - 1);
        bw.Flush();

        result.Add(md5, ms.ToArray());

        // Close the output stream.
        bw.Close();
        ms.Close();
    }

    // Close the reader and the connection.
    myReader.Close();
    con.Close();

    return result;
}
```

And I use it with PHP like this:

```
$o = new SoapClient('http://localhost:3153/IntranetConnect.svc?wsdl', array('trace' => 0, 'cache_wsdl' => WSDL_CACHE_NONE));
$pdf = $o->getPDF(array('pdfid' => 1109));

foreach($pdf->getPDFResult as $value) {
   header("Content-type: application/pdf");
   header('Content-disposition: filename='.$value->Key.'.pdf');
   echo $value->Value;
}
```